# MSI creates invalid registry entry names when run in the Windows docker container

Tags: docker, windows-installer

I have the old MSI package which during installation creates some of registry entries.

The root of the registry entries is named **TEST·ING** (please notice the dot, which is CHR(183)).

The setup creates these entries either via regular MSI **Registry** table or VBS custom action.

The ones created via VBS custom action ends up named like 'TEST�ING'.

It works fine when the installation is made on regular machine.

Looks like not a Docker problem but rather something related to language settings but the default language for non-Unicode programs is set to the English.

[image: Registry contents]

[image: Setup registry]

[image: Setup custom action]

[image: Docker container language]

Comment: Suggest you update your application to read from a registry key that does not contain this special character? Some ANSI / Unicode problem.

Comment: It cannot be done. This is an old setup, not something that was made recently.

Comment: Have you tried writing with Installscript? [First I could find](https://github.com/sengngykouch/Multimedia-Logic/blob/dd1869719fb1bb68d35187689be359c77a5d3ed7/Setup/MMLogic/Script%20Files/Setup.rul).

Comment: Nope, as it was mentioned, the problem comes from the old, quite complicated setup, that is working fine since years, on production or development machines. A quite a lot of it is written in VBScript so I would like to avoid updating it if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing Chr(183) with ChrW(183) in VBScript code did the job.

Comment: OK, Unicode. Nice, but can we ask why this character is used in the first place? Just wondering.

Comment: It has been in the project since about....15 years. Someone, long time ago must have had a very creative day :)

Comment: I thought it might be for testing, but if it works I guess that is case closed.